# docker not saving at wsl2 with -v and --mount

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume, wsl-2

I tried to run tensorflow container at wsl2, but there is trouble : my notebooks not saving.
My Dockerfile

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3-jupyter
COPY Notebooks/ Notebooks/
```

i run it with

```
docker run -it  --gpus all -p 8888:8888 -v /mnt/c/tflearn/tf1/Notebooks/:/Notebooks/ tflearn1
```

and my notebooks not saving (i saved it to Notebooks/ path), i dont know what to do, because previously its worked.Its builed good, GPU is  worked, all fine, but not saving. I tried to do with mount, but same issue - its not saving.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you have in mind?

Just for info, you mount the path from the host into the container! That means if /mnt/c/tflearn/tf1/Notebooks/ is empty it will be empty in the container too. You have to catch this with e.g. an entrypoint script.